# How to get data off a Windows partition when "primary GPT table is corrupt, but the backup appears OK"

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, live-usb, gpt

Was running Windows 8.1 on my Asus Laptop (U37VC). Blue screen; error 0xc000000e. Figure I've screwed up the boot somehow (some hard reboots lately after annoying lags). After disabling the boot protection in BIOS, I am able to run a utility (EasyRE) that is supposed to fix this from USB. Doesn't work; no partitions recognized.

Thought I would instead use Ubuntu to fix this. Am using Ubuntu 15.04 running off USB. GParted says "The primary GPT table is corrupt, but the backup appears OK, so that will be used."

Trying to run a few things in terminal:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount -t cifs -o ro /dev/sda6 /home/ubuntu/cdrive
mount.cifs: bad UNC (/dev/sda6)
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda6
Failed to determine whether /dev/sda6 is mounted: No such file or directory
Mounting volume... Failed to access '/dev/sda6': No such file or directory
Error opening '/dev/sda6': No such file or directory
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... Failed to access '/dev/sda6': No such file or directory
Error opening '/dev/sda6': No such file or directory
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: No such file or directory
Failed to access '/dev/sda6': No such file or directory
Error opening '/dev/sda6': No such file or directory
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

Volume is corrupt? OK, I'm suitably terrified. I should note that I have no idea what I'm doing here, this code is copy-paste from websites like this one.

Ideas? Most of my stuff is in the cloud but I'm a grad student and my precious Zotero files are not. Do I have a back-up? No, I'm an idiot. I hadn't cared about one because everything written by me (thus irreplaceable) is in Gmail; I forgot about Zotero until this calamity.

Please help. Is there a way of just fixing this? Or at least dragging the things I need off the drive? Is the drive itself OK? (Even if I can't get the data off I would like to know whether a clean install of Windows or Ubuntu would fix the problem) How do I check that?

EDITS: ---------------

```
Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048     616447     614400   300M EFI System
/dev/sda2      616448    1845247    1228800   600M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda3     1845248    2107391     262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4     2107392  782772223  780664832 372.3G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5   782772224  783515647     743424   363M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda6   783515648 1911560191 1128044544 537.9G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda7  1911560192 1953523711   41963520    20G Windows recovery environment
```

Perhaps extra bit of info that will prove revelatory to someone who knows what they're doing: When trying to repair using a Windows 8.1 install disk, it indicates that the drive is locked and that I should somehow "unlock" it.

OK, here's what I have from fdisk:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo sgdisk -b sda-backup.gpt /dev/sda
Caution: invalid main GPT header, but valid backup; regenerating main header
from backup!

****************************************************************************
Caution: Found protective or hybrid MBR and corrupt GPT. Using GPT, but disk
verification and recovery are STRONGLY recommended.
****************************************************************************
The operation has completed successfully.

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo sgdisk -p /dev/sda
Caution: invalid main GPT header, but valid backup; regenerating main header
from backup!

****************************************************************************
Caution: Found protective or hybrid MBR and corrupt GPT. Using GPT, but disk
verification and recovery are STRONGLY recommended.
****************************************************************************
Disk /dev/sda: 1953525168 sectors, 931.5 GiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): EA00449F-79EF-40B7-9A63-F062CED0EBBE
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 1953525134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 3437 sectors (1.7 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048          616447   300.0 MiB   EF00  EFI system partition
   2          616448         1845247   600.0 MiB   2700  Basic data partition
   3         1845248         2107391   128.0 MiB   0C01  Microsoft reserved ...
   4         2107392       782772223   372.3 GiB   0700  Basic data partition
   5       782772224       783515647   363.0 MiB   2700  
   6       783515648      1911560191   537.9 GiB   0700  Basic data partition
   7      1911560192      1953523711   20.0 GiB    2700  Basic data partition

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo gdisk /dev/sda
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.0

Caution: invalid main GPT header, but valid backup; regenerating main header
from backup!

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: damaged

****************************************************************************
Caution: Found protective or hybrid MBR and corrupt GPT. Using GPT, but disk
verification and recovery are STRONGLY recommended.
****************************************************************************

    Command (? for help): v

    Partition(s) in the protective MBR are too big for the disk! Creating a
    fresh protective or hybrid MBR is recommended.
```

So I copied the backup headers to the main (I hope this is what I did):

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo gdisk /dev/sdc
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.0

Partition table scan:
  MBR: MBR only
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present


***************************************************************
Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format
in memory. THIS OPERATION IS POTENTIALLY DESTRUCTIVE! Exit by
typing 'q' if you don't want to convert your MBR partitions
to GPT format!
***************************************************************


Command (? for help): q
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ gdisk /dev/sda

GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.0

Caution: invalid main GPT header, but valid backup; regenerating main header
from backup!

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: damaged

****************************************************************************
Caution: Found protective or hybrid MBR and corrupt GPT. Using GPT, but disk
verification and recovery are STRONGLY recommended.
****************************************************************************

Command (? for help): r

Recovery/transformation command (? for help): b

Recovery/transformation command (? for help): m

Command (? for help): w

Partition(s) in the protective MBR are too big for the disk! Creating a
fresh protective or hybrid MBR is recommended.

Final checks complete. About to write GPT data. THIS WILL OVERWRITE EXISTING
PARTITIONS!!

Do you want to proceed? (Y/N): y
OK; writing new GUID partition table (GPT) to /dev/sda.
Warning! An error was reported when writing the partition table! This error
MIGHT be harmless, or the disk might be damaged! Checking it is advisable.
```

Now I see OS (drive icon), DATA (drive icon), and UUI (USB icon) pop up at the side of my screen. Clicking on them yields nothing, but clicking on "DATA" in Nautilus yields "Error mounting /dev/sda6 at /media/ubuntu/DATA: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=999,gid=999" "/dev/sda6" "/media/ubuntu/DATA"' exited with non-zero exit status 1:"

Penultimate(?) Edit: --------

Whatever the second problem was, it was fixed somewhat using the EasyRE utility after using gdisk to copy over the backup GPT - at least enough to get back into Windows to grab my documents. I now have three partitions instead of the former two, though. A ~400GB C: with most of the important things; a 600MB D: called "Recovery" filled with "recovery" related things I think created by Windows, though could have been EasyRE using Windows tools; and a 400MB blank (though apparently 9/10 used according to Windows - Ubuntu shows the hidden files) E:. Ubuntu also shows a 315MB FAT "SYSTEM" partition. So I lost my former D: drive. I will try to figure out why over the next week, would of course appreciate any ideas.

Ubuntu notes I have two blocks of "Free Space": 599GB and 134MB. I assume recovering what was in its place before (D:) would be difficult.

Comment: Did you try with TestDisk utility? This might also help:  [Fix Partition Table Issues When Dual-booting Windows and Linux](http://www.reversiblean.com/fix-partition-table-issues-win-linux)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the [Common Internet File System (CIFS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block) is a network protocol, not a filesystem used on a hard disk. Thus, your attempt to mount the disk with CIFS was doomed to failure from the start. (You might use CIFS to access the same disk *from another computer,* but not locally.) Most Windows partitions use NTFS, which Ubuntu mounts using the NTFS-3g driver.

Second, using `ntfsfix` on the disk was also doomed to failure. Despite its name, `ntfsfix` doesn't actually fix anything significant; it does a few trivial checks and then marks the filesystem as requiring attention by Windows. Thus, if anything this step will make matters worse, since it might block attempts to access the filesystem from Linux. Also, it's not clear why you tried `/dev/sda6` with both `mount` and `ntfsfix`. Did you get that device ID from a disk utility, did you remember it was the correct device, or what? This is exactly the sort of technical information needed to help solve your problem.

Third and most importantly, the error message you report refers to the [GUID Partition Table (GPT),](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) which is a data structure a level *above* that of the filesystem. Thus, attempts to fix the filesystem are misplaced, at least at this stage. (It's like trying to bake the flour and eggs before you've combined them in the cake recipe.) Instead, you must look for a way to repair the partition table. Fortunately, GPT includes redundancy, so repairing it may well be possible. You've presented insufficient information to provide step-by-step instructions on doing so, though, and there's no simple set of data you could provide that would change that fact. There are any number of things that could be wrong, so from here on it must be a *process* of diagnosis and steps taken in response to things you learn, not a recipe.

To start, I recommend you read the following pages, in order:

1. [The GPT fdisk "What's a GPT?" page](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/whatsgpt.html)
2. [The Wikipedia page on GPT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) (you can actually skim most of this, but pay attention to the layout of data on the disk and the difference between the protective MBR, the two GPT headers, and the two partition tables)
3. [The GPT fdisk documentation on repairing problems](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html)

***Be patient!*** If you skip the first two pages and rush in to the third, your knowledge will be incomplete and you'll likely just make a hash of things. Once you've read these pages, you should be able to use `gdisk` to investigate your disk and, with any luck, repair it.

If you can't fix the disk with `gdisk`, you may be able to use [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to search the disk for filesystems and create a partition table that describes what it finds. This is definitely a utility of last resort, though.

Comment: This is all very helpful, thank you. I will learn about and use gdisk and come back. My using dev/sda6 was due to it being the drive where my most important documents are as assumed by the size shown by the code posted in my edit above.

Comment: You might want to know that on Ubuntu it says the package is of "bad quality" for what seems like a silly reason: Lintian check results for /home/ubuntu/Downloads/gdisk_1.0.0-1_amd64.deb:
E: gdisk: maintainer-address-malformed Rod Smith <rodsmith@nessus>

Comment: So I went through what I gathered I needed to do - I am guessing I need to use the b command. Is this correct?

Comment: There's a `gdisk` package included with Ubuntu. You can use that or the version available from Sourceforge, but the latter is intended for distributions that lack a native `gdisk` package, or in case you need an update to fix a bug or add a new feature that's critical to you. In any event, the backup GPT data that `gdisk` recovered look sensible, but I don't know offhand if the kernel would use them.  I'd fix the GPT data first, then try again with accessing your partitions. If partition-level access fails, then chances are there's a *second* problem, this one with the filesystem.

Comment: Mostly worked after copying over the backup and using EasyRE on it. C: partition is back; D: has disappeared. At least I have my important documents back - and backed up. 600GB poorer, though. Any ideas?